# package.json not found when instantiating node.js chaincode in Hyperledger Fabric 1.1

Tags: node.js, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I successfully configured a network with a few peers and one channel. I installed my chaincode successfully through the CLI container, but can't seem to instantiate it. When I run the instantiation command, it just hangs but it does create the container for the chaincode which exits because it cannot find the `package.json` in `/usr/local/src/package.json`.

What am I missing?

Here's the `docker logs` output for the chaincode container:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/src/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/src/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-06-01T13_47_55_486Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does your Node CC src directory actually have a package.json?

Comment: @GariSingh yes it does, along with a start script and one dependency..

Comment: How are you packaging and installing the chaincode?

Comment: @GariSingh The chaincode is not packaged before installing. It's just the .js file and a package.json. I'm installing with the command `peer chaincode install` which is successful. I'm following the commands in `utils.sh` script in the `fabric-samples` repo and no packaging seems to be in the script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you install the chaincode from the right directory. I installed mine from the root of the chaincode's folder, instead of the `node` folder within the chaincode's folder. If you use go you will need to install from the `go` folder.